# slurm allows authentication without allocation

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, slurm

I am using slurm with munge. Except on one node all others work fine.

But on one node, it is possible to ssh to it, even without any valid allocation.

I checked the sshd and system-auth file. They are exactly same on all nodes. I verified that munge is able decode the keys on server and client. I also checked the auth log to see if there is some clues. But I could not find any.

Can anyone help with the same

Answer (score 0):

Check your pam configuration for sshd (/etc/pam.d/sshd) and files included there. To check if the user has running job on node and allow login only in this case pam_slurm module can be used (and probably is on other nodes of your cluster). Module is distributed as contrib in main [slurm repository](https://github.com/SchedMD/slurm/blob/bcdd09d3386f4b4038ae9263b0e69d4d742988b2/contribs/pam/pam_slurm.c)